# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout When I try to inflate something

Tags: kotlin, layout-inflater, android-inflate

rerferfI'm trying to replicate this tutorial in Kotlin https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hfoXhiMTc0c
but when I made the inflate part got this error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to
> android.widget.LinearLayout

This is my code

> var bottomSheetDialog = BottomSheetDialog(this,
> R.style.Theme_Design_BottomSheetDialog)  var view: View =
> LayoutInflater.from(application).inflate(R.layout.recover_password_sheet,
> R.id.sheet_container as LinearLayout)

**custom_bottom_sheet.xml**

> `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"android:shape="rectangle">`
>
>  `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
> android:shape="rectangle">
>
> <solid android:color="@color/colorWhite"/>
> <corners
>     android:topLeftRadius="20dp"
>     android:topRightRadius="20dp"/> </shape>`

**recover_password_sheet.xml**

> `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
> xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
> android:id="@+id/sheet_container"
> android:layout_width="match_parent"
> android:layout_height="wrap_content"
> android:background="@drawable/custom_bottom_sheet"
> android:orientation="vertical">
>
> <TextView
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:gravity="center"
>     android:padding="15dp"
>     android:text="@string/forgot_password"
>     android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
>     android:textStyle="bold"/>
>
> <view
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="1dp"
>     android:background="@color/colorWhiteDivider"/>
>
>     <TextView
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:text="@string/forgot_password_description"
>         android:padding="20dp"
>         android:gravity="start"/>
>
>     <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
>         android:id="@+id/email"
>         android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
>         android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
>         android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
>
>         <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
>             android:id="@+id/txt_email"
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="50dp"
>             android:background="@drawable/custom_rounded_login_text_view"
>             android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon_username"
>             android:drawablePadding="10dp"
>             android:hint="@string/prompt_email"
>             android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
>             android:paddingLeft="20dp"
>             android:paddingRight="20dp" />
>
>     </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
>
>
> <view
>     android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="1dp"
>     android:background="@color/colorWhiteDivider"
>     android:paddingTop="20dp" />
>
> <Button
>     android:id="@+id/btn_accept"
>     android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="60dp"
>     android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
>     android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
>     android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
>     android:background="@drawable/custom_rounded_corner_icons"
>     android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
>     android:padding="20dp"
>     android:gravity="start"
>     android:textSize="15sp"
>     android:text="@string/accept"
>     android:textAlignment="center"
>     tools:ignore="RtlCompat" />`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies in the part:

```
R.id.sheet_container as LinearLayout
```

There you're trying to cast an integer (which represents a resource) into a `LinearLayout`.

Check the documentation on [LayoutInflater](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater) to find out which of the overloads of the `inflate` function better suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was the XML file and the .kt file

**Fixed XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:text="@string/forgot_password"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <View android:background="@color/colorWhiteDivider"
        android:layout_width = "match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/forgot_password_description"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:gravity="start"/>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/txt_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_rounded_login_text_view"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon_username"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:hint="@string/prompt_email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <View android:background="@color/colorWhiteDivider"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_width = "match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"/>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_accept"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_rounded_corner_icons"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:text="@string/accept"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        tools:ignore="RtlCompat" />


</LinearLayout>
```

**.kt files**

```
   var bottomSheetDialog = BottomSheetDialog(this)
   var view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.recover_password_sheet, null)
```

It works for me